# Fuzzy - NYSIIS python 3

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

fuzzy.c:1635:5: error: too few arguments to function 'PyCode_New'
I am upgrading from python 2.7 to 3.2.  I am getting an error in the c-compile of the fuzzy library (that apparently isn't Python 3 compatible).

Any suggestions?  Is there an alternative to the NYSIIS encoding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jellyfish supports Python 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look to see if that supports my needs